# Cannot relocate svn

Tags: subversion

I have to change my SVN repo URL so I run:

```
svn relocate [new_url]
```

Output:

```
svn: E170011: Repository moved temporarily to [new_url]
```

Running `echo $?` gives `1` back.
Operations like `checkout` are also causing the same issue.

Both `[new_url]`s are the same.

But when I run `svn info` it still shows the old URL.
If I try to commit changes it goes to the old repo.

How do I fix this issue? I'm using Subversion with Git for Windows.
I'm not using `git-svn`, I'm using the original subversion CLI.

Edit:
On the SVN server, I run this command:

```
svn checkout http://localhost/svn/testrepo
```

And it outputs:

```
Redirecting to URL 'http://localhost/svn/testrepo/':
svn: /build/subversion-owKwd0/subversion-1.13.0/subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c:1562: uri_skip_ancestor: Assertion `svn_uri_is_canonical(child_uri, NULL)' failed.
Aborted
```

I'm using apache2 server with dav_svn module to serve svn repos.

Apache2 Configuration (/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf):

```
Alias /svn /svn

<Location /svn>
 DAV svn
 SVNParentPath /svn
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Auth"
 AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
 <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
  Require valid-user
 </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What happens when you run `svn relocate [new_url]`? If you get any output, copy&paste it to the question. What is the exit code? What exactly means "I'm using Subversion with Git for Windows."? Do you use git-svn? Do you run `svn` commands in Git Bash? Git for Windows is neither Unix nor Linux.

Comment: Does it produce an error on `svn relocate`? The most common problem with it - incorrectly typed new address. In this case, the `svn` is unable to find repository on the new URL and abort the change. But it should give an easy to understood error about it. > I'm using Subversion with Git for Windows. So are you using SVN or GIT? Or some kind of weird cross, in which case all bets are off.

Comment: @bodo I've edited the question.

Comment: You did not provide all requested information in your question. Just to be sure about the exit code: Assuming you are using bash, show the output of `echo $?` after running `svn relocate ...` or in CMD `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`. Do you use CMD or Git Bash? Do you use git-svn? Is the URL in the error message really the same or maybe one with `http:` and the other with `https:`? On case you are overlooking something, pasting the real command and output to your question would allow us to spot errors.

Comment: @bodo Question updated. Please check it now.